# Use PHP to display an image for 5 minutes every time the hour changes

Tags: php, image, datetime

I have been looking for a way using php to display 'imageA.jpg' during 5 minutes every time the hour changes, and go back to displaying 'imageB.jpg' for the remaing 55 minutes - until 'imageA.jpg' is displaying again.

Example:

- 00:00 - 00:05 = display image A
- 00:06 - 00:59 = display image B
- 01:00 - 01:05 = display image A
- 01:06 - 01:59 = display image B

etc.

Comment: if you do it with php, the image wont change if i dont realod my browser page

Comment: Why don't you use javascript instead?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if (date('i') <= 5)
   echo "<img src="imageA.jpg" />";
else
   echo "<img src="imageB.jpg" />";
```

**EDIT:** The image will, of course, only change when you reload the page.